# Let $f$ be an irreducible monic polynomial of degree 4 over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Is $f$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm not sure whether the above is true as it came up while I was trying to answer another question. I have broken the attempted proof into two cases, but am stuck on the second.

Suppose $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. This may occur in two ways: 1) $f$ has a zero $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ or 2) $f$ factors as the product of irreducible quadratic polynomials.

Case 1: Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ is a zero of $f.$ As $f$ is monic and irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, it holds that $f$ is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. This implies that $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$. In particular, $[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p]=4$. The field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ contains both $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\alpha$, therefore $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^2}.$ Hence
\begin{equation*}
4= [\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p] \leq [\mathbb{F}_{p^2}:\mathbb{F}_{p}]=2,
\end{equation*}
a contradiction.

Case 2: Suppose $f=gh \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}[x],$ with $\deg(g)=\deg(h)=2.$ We may assume $g$ and $h$ to be irreducible, as if one is not then we are back in the first case. I don't see how to proceed from here, so I'm looking for a hint or counter-example.

Comment: Hint: if $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^4}$ is one of the roots, then the other roots are $\alpha^p, \alpha^{p^2}, \alpha^{p^3}$.  Then show that $(x - \alpha) (x - \alpha^{p^2}) \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}[x]$ and similarly for $(x - \alpha^p) (x - \alpha^{p^3})$.

Comment: Taking the first polynomial as example. It is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, therefore $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}.$ In particular then, the coefficients of the polynomial $x^2-(\alpha+\alpha^{p^2})x+\alpha^{p^2+1}$ must be in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ so $(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^{p^2})\in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}[x]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact $f$ cannot be irreducible over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ is a degree 4 extension of $\mathbb F_p$, and so is a degree $2$ extension of $\mathbb F_{p^2}$, implying that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ has degree 2. This polynomial will divide $f$.

(In Daniel Schleper's comment above, you can see explicitly what this minimal polynomial is.)